# Parse selected records from empty-line separated file

Tags: python, beginner, parsing

This is my first post here and I hope I will get some recommendations to improve my code. I have a parser which processes the file with the following structure:

```
SE|43171|ti|1|text|Distribution of metastases...
SE|43171|ti|1|entity|C0033522
SE|43171|ti|1|relation|C0686619|COEXISTS_WITH|C0279628

SE|43171|ab|2|text|The aim of this study...
SE|43171|ab|2|entity|C2744535
SE|43171|ab|2|relation|C0686619|PROCESS_OF|C0030705

SE|43171|ab|3|text|METHODS Between April 2014...
SE|43171|ab|3|entity|C1964257
SE|43171|ab|3|entity|C0033522
SE|43171|ab|3|relation|C0085198|INFER|C0279628
SE|43171|ab|3|relation|C0279628|PROCESS_OF|C0030705

SE|43171|ab|4|text|Lymph node stations...
SE|43171|ab|4|entity|C1518053
SE|43171|ab|4|entity|C1515946
```

Records (i.e., blocks) are separated by an empty line. Each line in a block starts with a `SE` tag; the `text` tag always occurs in the first line of each block (in the 4th field). The program extracts:

1. All `relation` tags in a block, and
2. Corresponding text (i.e., sentence ID (`sent_id`) and sentence text (`sent_text`)) from the first line of the block, if relation tag is present in a block. Please note that the relation tag is not necessarily present in each block.

Below is a mapping dictionary between tags and related fields in a file and a main program.

```
# Specify mappings to parse lines from input file
mappings = {
        "id": 1,
        "text": {
            "sent_id": 3,
            "sent_text": 5
        },
        "relation": {
            'subject': 5,
            'predicate': 6,
            'object': 7,
        }
    }
```

Finally a code:

```
def extraction(file_in):
    """This function extracts lines with 'text' and 'relation'
    tag in the 4th field."""
    extraction = {}
    file = open(file_in, encoding='utf-8')
    bla = {'text': []} # Create dict to store sent_id and sent_text
    for line in file:
        results = {'relations': []}
        if line.startswith('SE'):
            elements = line.strip().split('|')
            pmid = elements[1] # Extract number from the 2nd field
            
            if elements[4] == 'text':
                tmp = {}
                for key, idx in mappings['text'].items():
                    tmp[key] = elements[idx]
                bla['text'].append(tmp) # Append sent_id and sent_text
            
            if elements[4] == 'relation':
                tmp = {}
                for key, ind in mappings['relation'].items():
                        tmp[key] = elements[ind]
                tmp.update(sent_id = bla['text'][0]['sent_id'])
                tmp.update(sent_text = bla['text'][0]['sent_text'])
                results['relations'].append(tmp)
                extraction[pmid] = extraction.get(pmid, []) + results['relations']
        else:
           bla = {'text': []} # Empty dict to store new sent_id and text_id
    file.close()
    return extraction
```

The output looks like:

```
import json
print(json.dumps(extraction('test.txt'), indent=4))

{
    "43171": [
        {
            "subject": "C0686619",
            "predicate": "COEXISTS_WITH",
            "object": "C0279628",
            "sent_id": "1",
            "sent_text": "Distribution of lymph node metastases..."
        },
        {
            "subject": "C0686619",
            "predicate": "PROCESS_OF",
            "object": "C0030705",
            "sent_id": "2",
            "sent_text": "The aim of this study..."
        },
        {
            "subject": "C0085198",
            "predicate": "INFER",
            "object": "C0279628",
            "sent_id": "3",
            "sent_text": "METHODS Between April 2014..."
        },
        {
            "subject": "C0279628",
            "predicate": "PROCESS_OF",
            "object": "C0030705",
            "sent_id": "3",
            "sent_text": "METHODS Between April 2014..."
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks for any recommendation.

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview@SE. Shall parsing be lenient (allow variations as long as they are recognisable) or strict (e.g., insist on the 3rd part to abbreviate *title* or *abstract*, resp.)?

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't understand your question completely.

Comment: `extraction()`'s doc string is enough to refrain from commenting on not handling "`entity` lines". Documenting, or at least commenting on strictness would help the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing in your code is unreasonable and you've done a careful job. Nonetheless,
I would encourage you to decompose the parsing into smaller, simpler steps.

As a first step in that direction, a parsing function should take some text
(either a blob or an iterable of lines) and return or yield meaningful data. It
should not be concerned with the source of that text or the details of how to
obtain it (eg reading a file). So the top-level `extraction()` function should
just open the file and give the file handle to a separate parsing function. For
example:

```
def extraction(file_in):
    with open(file_in, encoding='utf-8') as fh:
        return parse(fh)
```

And the `parse()` function should also focus more tightly on orchestrating the
parsing steps and assembling the final data structure. In the illustration
below, notice that this design simplifies what one has to do to
test the parsing logic. Just feed it a list of lines -- no need to create a
file for the text. That's better for automated testing, better for quick
experimentation, better for sharing code with people on this website.

```
def parse(lines):
    extr = {}
    for rec in parse_records(lines):
        pmid, relations = parse_record(rec)
        extr.setdefault(pmid, []).extend(relations)
    return extr
```

Your data format implies two parsing phases. The first is to break the full
text into records (the blocks or paragraphs), as shown below. Notice how easy
this code is to understand: it's just breaking text apart into blank-line
delimited sections. Also notice that this function is general-purpose and can
be re-used in other parsing situations.

```
def parse_records(lines):
    rec = []
    for line in lines:
        if line.strip():
            rec.append(line)
        elif rec:
            yield rec
            rec = []
    if rec:
        yield rec
```

The second phase is to parse a single record. Just as we
relieved the parsing function of the burden of knowing about file
opening and reading, the record parser should be relieved of the
burden of knowing about the larger file structure. The function below
illustrates one way to parse the record. A few things worth noting. First, I
don't think your `mapping` dict is really helping you. Even though the impulse
to create it was understandable, it didn't truly allow you to
generalize/parameterize the parsing function (it still contained hard-coded
column locations, for example, and also had to know about the main sign posts
in the input text, specifically the tokens `SE`, `|`, `text`, and `relations`
and how to interpret them for parsing purposes). Since it didn't get you fully to re-usable
code, I would just embrace a little hard-coding. Second, notice how this code
is also easy to scan, read, and understand -- because it's doing so much less.
Finally, because of that tighter focus, the function is fairly easy to test now.
And that's important for this function because it's the one with the
most algorithmic complexity and potential for problems due to irregular
data.

```
def parse_record(rec):
    pmid = None
    sent_id = None
    sent_text = None
    relations = []
    for line in rec:
        if not line.startswith('SE'):
            continue
        xs = line.strip().split('|')
        row_type = xs[4]
        if row_type == 'text':
            pmid = xs[1]
            sent_id = xs[3]
            sent_text = xs[5]
        elif row_type == 'relation':
            relations.append({
                'subject': xs[5],
                'predicate': xs[6],
                'object': xs[7],
                'sent_id': sent_id,
                'sent_text': sent_text,
            })
    return (pmid, relations)
```

Comment: Great review, one suggestion. Given the requirements, in `parse_record` I would throw an exception when a line doesn't start with "SE" or when "text" is not in the first line.

Comment: @Marc Thanks for reminding me (at one point I had the same thought, but was too lazy or forgetful). Fixed. Other errors can occur in this function if the data is not fully regular, but the OP can address those specifics.